# Print result set without cursor

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I'm using T-SQL and I want to print out a result set. This is just a ~2x6 (dynamic size) set but I'm not entirely sure how I can do this without using a CURSOR. Is there a nice way I can print these to console/email/wherever?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print them from a bat file you can use osql.exe to execute the query - the results will be displayed to the screen.  You may want to use trunc and/or set colwidth settings so that it's legible.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you have two columns and six rows and you want to output them somehow without a cursor?

you can concatenate different rows without a cursor, e.g. assuming you have two string columns called col1 and col2:

```
declare @combined varchar(2000)
set @combined = ''

select @combined = @combined + char(13) + isnull(col1,'*') + ' ' + isnull(col2,'*')
from yourtable

print @combined
```